# Check if a string contains not defined characters

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a pre defined string as Follows.

```
string preDefined="abc"; // or i can use char array in here
string value="ac";
string value1="abw";
```

I need some function to compare value with preDefined.

```
 (value.SomefunctionContains(preDefined)
```

this function needs to return

```
value -> true;
value1 -> false
```

I knew that i can't use contains() or Any(). so plz help

Comment: Seems not a hard problem. Did you try _anything_ to solve it? You can check each character and check the original string has this character or not? There are some LINQ method to check them for example..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just looking for if `value` has any character that is not in `predefined`, so this should do it:

```
!value.Any(x => !predefined.Contains(x))
```

Or it's more clear using `All`:

```
value.All(predefined.Contains);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private bool SomeFunction(string preDefined, string str)
{
    foreach (char ch in str)
    {
        if (!preDefined.Contains(ch))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the following method to get the result :

```
private static bool DoesContain(string predefined, string value)
{
    char[] c_pre = predefined.ToCharArray();
    char[] c_val = value.ToCharArray();
    char[] intersection = c_pre.Intersect(c_val).ToArray();
    if (intersection.Length == c_val.Length) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please not that this solution is a generalized implementation. IT also returns true even if the characters are not in the same order, unless ther include all.